# How to ignore false values with System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net, system.text.json

I'm migrating from `Newtonsoft.Json` to `System.Text.Json` in my .NET Core 3.0 application. I'm trying to ignore false values.

In `System.Text.Json` I found the option to ignore null values:

```
JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
```

But I cannot find the option to ignore false values in `System.Text.Json`.

Does someone know how can this be achieved with `System.Text.Json`?

Or if someone know the equivalent of Newtonsoft `DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore` option that would be fantastic too.

Comment: I think you have to use Attribute [Default(false)] if I have understand you correct.

Comment: Thanks @AndreasSchmidt the attribute `[DefaultValue(false)]` is from `Newtonsoft.Json`. I would like to use `System.Text.Json`

Comment: I‘m pretty sure it‘s not from Newtonsoft.Json: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: sorry you are right @AndreasSchmidt! It's actually from `System.ComponentModel` namespace. Unfortunately `[DefaultValue(false)]` doesn't work.

Comment: You nee to ignore Properties with default values while desialization, right?

Comment: Correct. I would like to ignore properties that have the value `false`.

Comment: Seems like this is not currently implemented.  [`JsonSerializer.Write.HandleObject.cs`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/48363ac826ccf66fbe31a5dcb1dc2aab9a7dd768/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializer.Write.HandleObject.cs) is where the properties of an object are written.  There is a check for `jsonPropertyInfo.IgnoreNullValues`, and `jsonPropertyInfo.ShouldSerialize` -- but no checks for a default value, nor any check for a custom `ShouldSerializeXXX()` method.

Comment: So your option currently is to implement a custom [`JsonConverter<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1?view=netcore-3.0) for classes where you want to ignore `false` values when writing.

Comment: Thanks @dbc. I'm not sure how can I skip a property with a `JsonConverter<T>`.

Comment: @stevo - When you write a `JsonConverter<T>` for a particular type `T` you have to write everything manually, so if you don't want to write a property, then just don't.  If you're asking how to write a generic `JsonConverter<T>` that works for all types `T` then that's much more complex.

Comment: @dbc unfortunately that's not true. You're only in charge of writing the value, the property name is already written. So if you don't write it, you get an invalid JSON

Answer (score 19):

This is implemented in [.Net 5.0](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/41313):

> Support ignoring value-type defaults

This version introduces [`JsonIgnoreCondition`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.0-rtm.20519.4/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonIgnoreCondition.cs) enum:

> ```
> /// When specified on JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition,
> /// determines when properties and fields across the type graph are ignored.
> /// When specified on JsonIgnoreAttribute.Condition, controls whether
> /// a property is ignored during serialization and deserialization. This option
> /// overrides the setting on JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition.
> public enum JsonIgnoreCondition
> {
>     /// Property is never ignored during serialization or deserialization.
>     Never = 0,
>     /// Property is always ignored during serialization and deserialization.
>     Always = 1,
>     /// If the value is the default, the property is ignored during serialization.
>     /// This is applied to both reference and value-type properties and fields.
>     WhenWritingDefault = 2,
>     /// If the value is <see langword="null"/>, the property is ignored during serialization.
>     /// This is applied only to reference-type properties and fields.
>     WhenWritingNull = 3,
> }
> ```

Specifically [`JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignorecondition?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_Serialization_JsonIgnoreCondition_WhenWritingDefault) will suppress `false` Boolean values.  It may be applied in one of two ways.  Firstly, you can apply it directly to a member using [`JsonIgnoreAttribute.Condition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute.condition?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_Serialization_JsonIgnoreAttribute_Condition):

```
public class Model
{
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lsfSfd).

Secondly, you may set it in [`JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.defaultignorecondition?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_DefaultIgnoreCondition):

> Specifies a condition to determine when properties with default values are ignored during serialization or deserialization. The default value is [Never](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignorecondition?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_Serialization_JsonIgnoreCondition_Never).

I.e. given the following model:

```
public class Model
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}
```

You may serialize it as follows to skip serialization of `false` values in runtime:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault };
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(model, options);
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lNLUrS).

Notes:

1. The [.Net 5.0 docs for `JsonIgnoreCondition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignorecondition?view=net-5.0) appear to have some inaccuracies.  Firstly, they claim that `WhenWritingDefault` means that

   > Property will only be ignored if it is `null`.

   However, in fact the property will be ignored if it is **`default`** as stated in the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.0-rtm.20519.4/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonIgnoreCondition.cs).

   Secondly, they claim that `WhenWritingNull`

   > is applied only to reference-type properties and fields.

   However, testing shows that it applies to [nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) value type members as well.  E.g. given the model:

   ```cs
   public class Model
   {
       public bool? Value { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Serializing with `DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault` omits `Value` when it it is null:

   ```
   var model = new Model(); // Leave value null

   var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault };
   Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(model, options)); // Prints {}
   ```

   Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GXAe9H).
2. Setting `JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault` applies to **all value types** not just `bool`.  Thus if you have any `double`, `int`, `DateTime`, `decimal` (including a zero-valued decimal with a specified number of digits such as `decimal.Parse("0.0000")`) or other value type members, they will be omitted when the value equals the default.

   There does not appear to be a way to globally skip serialization of only default `bool` valued members while still serializing other value-type members, which could be done in Json.NET via a custom contract resolver.

   Demo fiddle #4 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C7UMOQ).
3. In determining whether a member has a default value, the default value for the *type of the value* (i.e. `default(T)`) is used.  Unlike [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DefaultValueAttributeIgnore.htm), [`DefaultValueAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute?view=net-5.0) is not taken into consideration.

   Demo fiddle #5 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CjA60T).
4. Prior to .Net 5.0 you would need to create a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to) for the containing type (i.e. `Model` in the above examples) and manually skip or serialize each member as desired.

Comment: [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-7-0#ignore-individual-properties) about System.Text.Json serialization covers what the `JsonSerializerOptions` mean