# What is the equivalent of Newtonsoft.Json DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore option in System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net, system.text.json

I'm migrating from `Newtonsoft.Json` to `System.Text.Json` in my .NET Core 3.0 application.

How do I get have the same behaviour with `System.Text.Json` as I have in my .NET Core 2.2 app with `Newtonsoft.Json` configured with `DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore`? You can find the `DefaultValueHandling` option described [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm).

Comment: Do you need [`System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute?view=net-5.0) to be honored in determining whether a property has a default value?  If not, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64865628/3744182) to the related question [How to ignore false values with System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58225273/3744182).

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be help

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true);
```

Comment: Thanks @Gökten Karadağ! It does help but you will still get all false values for example.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this, at least not in an easy way. You can easily ignore `null` values using `IgnoreVullValues` property of `JsonSerializerOptions` class but this will only ignore `null` values and still serialize integers, booleans etc. with default values.
You can find more about `JsonSerializerOptions` class [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions?view=netcore-3.0)

Comment: Thanks @byczu for your answers! I'm afraid you are right. I might need to switch back to `Newtonsoft.Json`

Answer (score 2):

Please try this library I wrote as an extension to System.Text.Json to offer missing features: https://github.com/dahomey-technologies/Dahomey.Json.

You will find support for ignoring default values:

```
using Dahomey.Json;
using Dahomey.Json.Attributes;
using System.Text.Json;

public class ObjectWithDefaultValue
{
    [JsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    [DefaultValue(12)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    [DefaultValue("foo")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    [DefaultValue("foo")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    [DefaultValue(12)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Setup json extensions by calling on JsonSerializerOptions the extension method SetupExtensions defined in the namespace Dahomey.Json:
Then serialize your class with the regular Sytem.Text.Json API:

```
public void Test()
{
    JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
    options.SetupExtensions();

    ObjectWithDefaultValue obj = new ObjectWithDefaultValue
    {
        Id = 13,
        FirstName = "foo",
        LastName = "bar",
        Age = 12
    };

    string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj, options); // {"Id":13,"LastName":"bar"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a proposed api-suggestion [#42635](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/42635) for ignoring default values that has been added to .NET Core 5.0 release due out in November 2020. Newtonsoft currently is the only supported solution worth using for this particular issue.