# System.Text.Json - DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore alternative

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json

I checked 3 years old threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58226377/what-is-the-equivalent-of-newtonsoft-json-defaultvaluehandling-defaultvaluehan) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/779) and they state that it's not possible to set `DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore` using `System.Text.Json` and some people switched back to `Json.NET` because of that. Is there a way to do that today, 3 years later?

### Json.NET way

```cs
[JsonProperty("pair", DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
public string[]? Symbols { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation you can use JsonIgnore with conditions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0

```
public class Forecast
{
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.Never)]
    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
    public string? Summary { get; set; }
};
```